# ¿Como poner stop (parar) al stream en el reproductor de mi web? js

Tags: javascript, html5, web, audio

tengo una duda sobre como parar el reproductor de mi radio y que al darle de nuevo play se vuelva a cargar en vivo y no de donde se quedo. El codigo que tengo funciona todo bien, solo que al darle a stop se pone en pausa y al volver suena desde donde se quedo y el oyente no vuelve a escuchar la radio en vivo sino atrasado.

este es mi codigo:

```
<div class="et_pb_code_inner">
<audio src="https://radios.solumedia.com/6424/stream" type="audio/mpeg" preload="none"></audio>
<a class="letraradio"><button id="boton" style="font-family: 'ETmodules'!important; content: attr(data-icon);">E</button></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
var sound = false;
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (!sound) {
    v.play();
    this.innerHTML = "`";
    sound = true;
  } else {
    v.pause();
    this.innerHTML = "E";
    sound = false;
    
  }
});
</script>
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias manera: agregando una función al evento pause, recargando el audio al hacer playa, entre otros.

Yo opte en mostrarte una solución, y que ize una prueba y funciona, y es lo más fácil que se pueda hacer.

Es `currentTime`. Esto hace que el audio comienze en un determinado tiempo que queramos. Y le pasamos un tiempo **0**, el audio vuelve a reproducir.

```
v.currentTime = 0;
```

Quedaría hecho así en el `else`, al hacer pause (al hacer playa no funcionaria):

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0]; 
var sound = false; 
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.addEventListener("click", function() { 
 
 if (!sound) { 
  
  v.play(); 
  this.innerHTML = "`"; 
  sound = true; 
  
 } else { 
  
  v.pause(); 
  v.currentTime = 0;
  this.innerHTML = "E"; 
  sound = false; 
  
 } 

});
```

En caso de que el anterior no funcione, aquí hay otra solución, usando una función de `load()` en un tiempo `setTimeout()` predefinido (sin agregar un tiempo):

```js
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0]; 
var sound = false; 
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.addEventListener("click", function() { 
 
 if (!sound) { 
  
  v.play(); 
  this.innerHTML = "`"; 
  sound = true; 
  
 } else { 
  
  v.pause(); 
  //v.currentTime = 0;
  this.innerHTML = "E"; 
  sound = false; 
  
  setTimeout(function () { 
   v.load();
  });
  
 } 

});
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_code_inner"> 
  
  <audio src="https://radios.solumedia.com/6424/stream" type="audio/mpeg" preload="none"></audio> 
  
  <a class="letraradio">
   <button id="boton" style="font-family: 'ETmodules'!important; content: attr(data-icon);">E</button>
  </a> 
 
 </div>
```

Hay más respuesta similar en [Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42125087/13003076).
Espero que sirva.

Comment: Si te sirvió el ejemplo, y si te fue de ayuda, marca la respuesta con ✓ para que eyude a otros que necesiten. O buscaremos otra solución

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me dio una idea.
Probé la primera y no funcionaba y la segunda ya me funciono mejor pero como que  a veces no cargaba.

Answer (score 1):

Al final pude solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

js
´´´

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
var sound = false;
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (!sound) {
    v.play();
    this.innerHTML = "`";
    sound = true;
  } else {
    v.pause();
    v.currentTime = 0;
    sound = false;
    v.load();
    this.innerHTML = "E";
  }
});
```

´´´
muchas gracias por la ayuda :)